# If $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, is $G/H \times H \cong G$?

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

If $ H $ is a normal subgroup of $ G $, is $ G/H \times H \cong G $?

For example, I think $ \mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z} \times 2 \mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z} $. I would construct a map as follows:
\begin{align}
\phi: \mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z} \times 2 \mathbb{Z} &\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}; \\
      (a,b)                                       &\longmapsto     a + b.
\end{align}
If it is not true in general, then are there a few criteria to show when it is true?

Thanks!

Comment: For the record, I would like math to work this way.

Comment: Also, is there a nicer way to format that map? Like, on two lines? With the arrows lining up nicely?

Comment: Sadly math does not work this way. Notice that your LHS is not cyclic and has elements of finite order.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension . This is almost never true.

Comment: Hmm... it seems so strange and sad that we can 'kill' H in G, but we can't fix the damage we've done? Is there maybe a different operation for 'resuscitating' H in G? I'm just concerned for H is all.

Comment: It works for vector spaces. Go vector spaces, go!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. If $A\times B\cong G$ then *both* $A$ and $B$ (respectively their images under the isomorphism) are normal in $G$. Your example with $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ does not work because $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ is not normal in $\mathbb Z$, yes it is not even a subgroup (no nonzero element $x\in \mathbb Z$ has the property $x+x=0$).

Answer (score 10):

Let me add a couple of comments to the other excellent answers.

In some cases there is a subgroup $K$ of $G$ such that $G = H K$ and $H \cap K = 1$. Then $G/H \cong K$, and $G$ is a [semidirect product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product) (a.k.a. split extension) $H \rtimes K$ of $H$ by $K$. The semidirect product can be regarded as a generalization of the direct product, in which only one of the factors is normal.

In general, even such a subgroup $K$ of $G$ will not exist. Define then $K = G/H$. Now $G$ is said to be an [extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension) of $H$ by $K$. Things get immediately very difficult here. However, one can define a section as a *map* $\sigma : K \to G$ such that $\varphi \circ \sigma = \textbf{1}_{K}$. (Here $\varphi : G \to K = G/H$ is the canonical map.) $\sigma(K)$ will not be a subgroup of $G$ (unless $G$ is a split extension of $H$ by $K$ as above), but the multiplication between elements of $\sigma(K)$ will have to be corrected by an element of $H$. This yields what is called a $1$-cocycle, and from now on you are in the territory of [group cohomology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_cohomology).

Comment: Is it necessary for the map $\sigma$ to be a homomorphism? Or is it just any well-defined map that works as a right-hand inverse for the canonical projection?

Comment: @MiguelAngelAlarconBustos, apologies for the late answer. There is a $\sigma$ which is a homomorphism if and only if $G$ is a split extension. Think of the case when $G$ is cyclic of order $4$, and $K$ is the subgroup of order $2$.

Answer (score 5):

Any cyclic group whose order is not squarefree contains at least one normal subgroup for which this fails, as $C_{p^2m}\not\cong C_{p}\times C_{pm}$.

You may be looking for the [Schur-Zassenhaus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Zassenhaus_theorem) theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Two trivial cases where this is true are $H = \{ 1 \}$ and $H = G$. Also, there exist many groups for which these are the only cases. One example is $S_3$, the nonabelian group of order $6$. If $S_3 \cong A \times B$, then $A = \{1\}$ or $A = S_3$.

Comment: $\mathbb Z_4$ is an even smaller example!

Comment: @yatima2975: you're right, Thanks. The cyclic groups of orders $1$, $2$, and $3$ are also examples, and more generally cyclic groups of prime power order give examples.

Comment: Orders 1,2 and 3 don't work because there a subgroup is either trivial or the whole group!

Comment: I meant to give examples of indecomposable groups, not necessarily those where the statement fails. It fails for an indecomposable group unless it is of prime order or trivial

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that even when $G \cong H \times K$, in order for $G/H \times H$ to be isomorphic to $G$, you need to pick the "right" copy of $H$.

For example, let $G = C_2 \times C_4$, let $H = C_2$, and let $F = \{0\} \times \{0, 2\}$ be a subgroup of $G$.  Then $F \cong H$ and, since $G$ is abelian, $F$ is a normal subgroup.  However,
$$(G/F) \times H \cong C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2 \ncong G.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Supplementary Answer**:

This fact is quoted from [Serre's Course in Arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321176/if-h-is-a-normal-subgroup-of-g-is-g-h-times-h-cong-g)(p.16 lemma).

> **Fact**
>   Let $A,C$ are finite Abelian groups with their orders are prime to each other.
>   If we have exact sequence of Abelian groups
>   $$
> 0\to A\to B\to C\to 0
> $$
>
> then $B\cong A\times C$.

Especially,let $G$ be a finite Abelian group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$,we have 
$$
0\to H\to G\to G/H\to 0.
$$

So if gcd$(|H|,|G/H|)=1$, then $G\cong G/H\times H$.