# If $G$ contains a normal subgroup $H \cong \mathbb{Z_2}$ such that $G/H$ is infinite cyclic, then $G \cong \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z_2}$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group containing a normal subgroup $H \cong \mathbb{Z_2}$ such that $G/H$ is infinite cyclic. Then $G \cong \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z_2}$.

Since $G/H$ is infinite cyclic it's isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. And since $H \cong \mathbb{Z_2}$, we have $G/H \times H \cong \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z_2}$. So the question now is can we make $G/H \times H \cong G$ (without any recourse to the Isomorphism theorems please)?

Any hints appreciated.

Comment: No, this strategy does not work. It's not hard to find examples of groups $G$ and normal subgroups $H$ such that $G/H \times H \not\approx G$. See for example http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321176/if-h-is-a-normal-subgroup-of-g-is-g-h-times-h-cong-g?rq=1.

Comment: @LeeMosher it actually does work in this case because $G/H$ is free abelian.

Comment: @LeeMosher It works in this case though due to: $G/H$ is infinite cyclic, hence $G$ has a subgroup $K$ isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$, *and* $K$ is of index $2$.

Comment: Yes, if the quotient group $G$ is cyclic then there is a section. And then yes, if on top of that the kernel is so simple as to have no isomorphisms then it must be a product. But the OP should understand that those are very, very strong hypotheses on $G$ and $H$.

Comment: I still don't understand how $G/H \times H \cong G$

Answer (score 1):

Let $p:G\rightarrow G/H$ be the quotient map and $x$ such that $p(x)=1$. Consider $f:Z/2\times Z\rightarrow G$ defined by $f(u,v)=ux^v$

Comment: I have trouble understanding how $u,v$, and $x$ behave in the expression $ux^v$? How would $f(0,3)$ and $f(0,2)$ differ from each other?

Answer (score 1):

Let $H = \{ e, h \}$. Notice that $h^2 = e$. Since $H$ is normal, it follows that $xHx^{-1} = H$ for every $x \in G$, i.e. $\{ e, xhx^{-1} \} = \{ e, h \}$, whence it follows that $x h x^{-1} = h$, i.e. $xh = hx$, so $h$ commutes with every $x \in G$.

Let $\hat g$ be a generator of $G/H$. Let $\pi : G \to G/H$ be the natural projection. Choose a $g \in \pi ^{-1} (\hat g)$ (there are only two possibilities for $g$, any of them will do).

If $x \in G$, then $\pi(x) \in G/H$ so there exist a unique $m_x \in \Bbb Z$ such that $\pi(x) = \hat g ^{m_x}$. In this case it is true that either $x = g^{m_x}$, or $x = g^{m_x} h$. In other words, for every $x \in G$ there exist unique $m \in \Bbb Z$ and $a \in \{0, 1\}$ such that $x = g^m h^a$.

> Define $f : G \to \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z_2$ by $f(x) = f(g^m h^a) = (m, \bar a)$.

Notice that if $x = g^m h^a$ and $y = g^n h^b$ then (using the fact that $h$ commutes with everybody)

$$f(xy) = f(g^m h^a g^n h^b) = f(g^m g^n h^a h^b) = f(g^{m+n} h^{a+b}) = (m+n, \overline {a+b}) = (m, \bar a) + (n, \bar b) = \\
f(g^m h^a) + f(g^n h^b) = f(x) + f(y) ,$$

which shows that $f$ is a group homomorphism.

If $f(x) = f(g^m h^a) = (0, \bar 0)$ then $(m, \bar a) = (a, \bar 0)$, whence it follows that $m=0$ and $2 \mid a$, so $a = 2b$, and then $h^a = h^{2b} = (h^2)^b = e^b = e$, showing that $x=e$, so $f$ is injective.

Finally, for $(m, \alpha) \in \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z_2$, choose $a \in \{0,1\}$ a representative for $\alpha$ and notice that $\bar a = \alpha$, so $f(g^m h^a) = (m, \bar a) = (m, \alpha)$, which shows that $f$ is surjective.

We conclude that $f$ is an isomorphism.