# On properties of quotients in the abelian category

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose A is an Abelian group, and B a subgroup. Moreover, suppose A/B = C  is a Free Abelian group.Then, we have A is isomorphic to: $$B \oplus C$$. Is there an elementary proof of this without the use of category theory? Thanks.

Comment: Are you taking about internal direct product?

Comment: I mean the direct sum or direct product externally. C is not a subgroup of A and so we cannot talk about the internal direct product.

Comment: Using a basis of $C$ you can get a map $C\to A$, splitting the projection map $A\to C$, whose image is a copy of $C$ in $A$ which is a complementary summand to $B$.

Comment: See,https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321176/if-h-is-a-normal-subgroup-of-g-is-g-h-times-h-cong-g

Comment: @Angina Seng How do you get the splitting map? I understand you could build a random homomorphism from C to A by using an arbitrary map from a generating set of C to A, and then using the Universal property. But how do you ensure that it is a splitting map?

Comment: @Subhajit This does not to answer my question as it pertains only to finite groups and semi-direct products.

Comment: Take Z₄ , G be subgroup of order 2, then Z₄/G = H , since H and G both isomorphic to Z₂, Z₄ can't be isomorphic to the product G×H.

Comment: @Subajit I specifically said that the quotient must be a Free Abelian group. The fact that it is free means it is a group with a set of generators and only one relation i.e. commutator relation. For example, you can take C  to be the integers. Your example is for finite groups, and does not apply here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we think of abelian groups as $\mathbb Z$-modules then a free abelian group is just a free $\mathbb Z$-module.  It's a standard result in homological algebra that if the last module in a short exact sequence is projective (free modules are projective) then the sequence splits.

The proof is very concrete.  Let $f\colon A \to C$ be the map with kernel $B$ that factors to an isomorphism $A/B \simeq C$.  As $C$ is free we can define a map $g\colon C \to A$ that sends each basis element $x \in C$ to some choice of element in $f^{-1}(x)$.  Then $gf$ is the identity on $C$.  Now the image of $g$ and the kernel of $f$ are submodules of $A$.  Prove that these submodules generate $A$ and have trivial intersection, so $A = \mathrm{im} \ g \oplus \ker f$.  Then note that the image is isomorphic to $C$ and the kernel is $B$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That clears it up.